# @deprecated — Instead of passing separate callback arguments, use an observer argument

Tags: angular, typescript

I tried to fix the issue but it is not working so I could not find another way to solve the issue. Can someone help me fix the issue?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xDDZ4.png) Here is the code

Comment: `.subscribe({next: data => console.log(data), error: error => console.log(error)})`

Answer (score 0):

You're missing the curly braces in your code :

```
myObs$.subscribe(() => {
 // next code 
})
```